# Trying to transfer over to Outlook 2007 from Outlook Express on different computers

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am currently trying to learn Outlook 2007.

1) Trying to transfer or download existing messages from Outlook Express on older PC operating in Windows XP to newer PC operating on Windows 7.

2) How do I set up to receive all emails on multiple computers?

Comment: Outlook has the ability to import Outlook Express email have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

1) Outlook will happily import Outlook Express data, which is typically located in `C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities\{GUID}\Microsoft\Outlook Express`

2) The exact way to get there depends on which version of Outlook you're using, but here's the general idea:

1. Tools
2. Accounts
3. Double-click on your account
4. Advanced tab
5. Check all three boxes at the bottom

This applies to Outlook, Outlook Express, Windows Mail and Windows Live Mail.

Answer (score 0):

To your Question

> 2) How do I set up to receive all emails on multiple computers?

Depending on the provider, ie Gmail, Hotmail ect...

Check the option to LEAVE a copy of the email on the server.

That way you can receive it on any computer and as many times as you wish.

If you are like me, and handle "gzilions" of emails.

I advice you to also check the Delete from server when deleted in my local email. That way you will prevent running out of space on the server.